# Updating ARIMA forecasting in Python

Tags: python, time-series

I have a series with 3068 observations. 
I would like to generate an ARIMA(0,1,1) model for the first 3037 observation and with this model predict the 3038th one by 3037th actual observation. 
And then I would like to update this ARIMA(0,1,1) model with 3038 actual observation and with this model predict the 3039th one by 3038th actual observation. 
And go on...
Some draft code examples will be appreciated.

Comment: Try [PyFlux](http://www.pyflux.com/docs/getting_started.html)

Comment: So you copied a piece of code from the internet and surprisingly it does not do what you want? What exactly is it suppodes to do, and what does it do instead?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that updating the whole ARIMA model is fast but as yet I also haven't found the way to append only the next observed value to the model. My code for full model re-fit:

```
    for t in range(len(test)):
        model = ARIMA(history, order=(ar, i, ma))
        model_fit = model.fit(disp=0, solver=solver, max_iter=max_iter)
        output = model_fit.forecast()
        yhat = output[0]
        predictions.append(yhat)
        obs = test[t]  # the real observation (the expected value)
        history.append(obs)
```

You can also circumvent full model re-fit for each new observation by predicting more than a single value at one step.
My code to predict all the values in one go (with a safety net that the model might not be able to predict all your required points):

```
    iter = 0
    while iter < len(test):
        model = ARIMA(history, order=(ar, i, ma))
        model_fit = model.fit(disp=0, solver=solver)
        remaining_steps = len(test)-iter
        yhats, _, _ = model_fit.forecast(steps=remaining_steps)
        len_new = len(yhats)  # length of new predictions
        predictions = numpy.concatenate([predictions, yhats])
        history = numpy.concatenate([history, test[iter:iter+len_new]])
        iter += len_new
```

This is a relevant answer on how it can be done in R: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/34191/149565

Answer (score 0):

Having the same question in my mind while playing around with Statsmodels API, I found the pyramid API very helpful. The **auto_arima()** function lets you add new observations. Here is an example http://www.alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/0.9.0/auto_examples/arima/example_add_new_samples.html